# How to implement trailing of object in Libgdx

Tags: swing, libgdx

How could I create trailing for object like this fun game by using Libgdx framework:

[Swinging taxi](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.llg.swingingtaxi)

You can take a look at this video to understand what I'm talking about

[Swinging taxi youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_ozxalG-tx8&feature=youtu.be)

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: By trailing you mean the shape behind the vehicle?

Comment: @DavidPeicho yes, I do

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at [this](https://github.com/mattdesl/lwjgl-basics/wiki/LibGDX-Finger-Swipe) tutorial. It's implemented in a different way than you would be doing it, but it seems like it's essentially the same effect.

Comment: Thank you @grimrader22. I will take a look at link you shared